# VBScript error: path not found

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a problem in VBScript. I get an error when I run this script. It says 'path not found'.

```
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript"> 
Option Explicit    
dim filesys, filetxt 
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8  
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If not filesys.FileExists("%USERPROFILE%\CAD_Kunde\CAD_Kunde.txt") Then 
    Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("%USERPROFILE%\CAD_Kunde\CAD_Kunde.txt", ForWriting, True)  
    filetxt.WriteLine ("1")
 filetxt.Close 
End If

</script>
```

Comment: What have you done yourself? Does it work when you put in an existing location (C:\temp) instead of `%USERPROFILE%`? Does it work when you put in your userlocation (C:\Documents and Setting\yourusername) instead of `%USERPROFILE&`? Have you tried [google](http://www.google.nl/search?q=vbscript+USERPROFILE)?

Comment: i had it done with (C:\temp) before but now i want to do it in the user profile. With C:\Documents and Setting\myusername it doesnt worked same error. Yes i tried google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to approach this problem. (I could give the solution in a oneliner, but what is the <strike>fun</strike> learning in that?)

1. Appearently, %USERPROFILE% does not get recognized by the Scripting.FileSystem COM. So we have to replace it manually by the appropriate value.
2. %USERPROFILE% is an [environment variable](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_data_environment.php). System variables can be retrieved through the ExpandEnvironmentStrings method of the Shell object. So you have to create the shell object with: `Set WShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")`
3. Now you can call the [ExpandEnvironmentsStrings](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/quickref/wshshell_ExpandEnvironmentStrings.html) method on the Wshell object. It returns the User Profile String
4. Use the returned string in the path.